# NPE in CSRFGuard

Tags: java, csrf, owasp

I want to protect my app from csrf, so I add owasp.csrf.jar and configure my app as described [here](https://github.com/esheri3/OWASP-CSRFGuard) Then I add hidden field to one of my forms with csrf token tags, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<csrf:token-name/>" value="<csrf:token-value/>" />
```

but when my page is rendering I get NPE in **TokenNameTag.java**

What have I missed?

**UPDATE**

The stacktrace:

```
2013-04-15 10:46:49,985 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/myapp].[jsp]]  Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.tag.TokenNameTag.doStartTag(TokenNameTag.java:45)
    at org.apache.jsp.struts.config.configurationMain_jsp._jspx_meth_csrf_005ftoken_002dname_005f0(configurationMain_jsp.java:7405)
    at org.apache.jsp.struts.config.configurationMain_jsp._jspx_meth_html_005fform_005f7(configurationMain_jsp.java:6812)
    at org.apache.jsp.struts.config.configurationMain_jsp._jspx_meth_logic_005fmatch_005f3(configurationMain_jsp.java:6695)
    at org.apache.jsp.struts.config.configurationMain_jsp._jspService(configurationMain_jsp.java:1712)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1069)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:455)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:279)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:507)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: I've updated my question, but don't think that it can help you

Comment: It looks to be in that the library you're using - have you looked into the issues listed on the github repo you linked to? If they don't cover your problem, I'd open a new one.

Comment: There is one there concerning NPE in filter, but no one concerning TokenNameTag

Comment: Are you able to find the fix it? Please share the fix.

Comment: What version of CSRFGuard do you use when you get that exception?

Comment: @minil could you please provide the version (duplicating the comment with member login to force notification)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `TokenNameTag.java` on line 45. Here is my stack-trace

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause                                                                                                                                                                                
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)                                                                                                                                                            
at org.owasp.csrfguard.tag.TokenNameTag.doStartTag(TokenNameTag.java:45)                                                                                                                            
at org.apache.jsp.position_005fdetails_jsp._jspx_meth_csrf_005ftokenname_005f0(position_005fdetails_jsp.java:4768) org.apache.jsp.position_005fdetails_jsp._jspService(position_005fdetails_jsp.java:1255) at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)                                                                                                                               at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)`
```

The problem for me was that I had not copied the following into the `web.xml` file

```
<listener>
            <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
       </listener>
       <listener>
            <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
       </listener>
       <context-param>
             <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
             <param-value>Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties</param-value>
       </context-param>


<servlet> 
     <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name> 
     <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet</servlet-class> 

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/JavaScriptServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<filter>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

After I did this then it worked for me.

(Just for completeness sake, I will add that the `owasp.csrfguard-3.1.0.jar` has to be in the `lib` directory and also the `Owasp.CsrfGuard.properties` has to be in the correct directory with one possibility being the application classpath - see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Installation)